# Quick and easy way to make data unrecoverable from a USB stick

Tags: macos

I have some sensitive data on my macbook. One of my hard disks is an SSD. All I want is to be able to insert my USB and open a script or program and have it overwrite or unrecoverably delete or unrecoverably encrypt everything on all disks even the boot disk except maybe important system files that are currently open and hard to delete. I don't want to have to go through dialogs and installations. Then I want to be able to remove my USB and have it continue working.

Is there something I can use for this? The best I could think of is a script with rm -rf on a USB stick but that would be recoverable.

Comment: I am assuming by this method you need something very quick, otherwise why skip the dialog and confirmations in any legitimate scenario... Problem is any activity that will significantly reduce the possibility of data recovery will take significant time. Note that some SSD drives have this functionality embedded in the drives firmware, depending on the manufacturer and model, you may be able to call that routine, it would be far more reliable and quick than anything the OS can do. I still question the legitimacy of this, sounds like a thumbstick bomb to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-P` switch with the `rm` command. The `-P` overwrites the deleted files 3 times with data.

```
rm -rP /path/to/files
```

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rm.1.html

---

There are also 3rd party tools like [Blancco 5](https://www.blancco.com/technology-solutions/secure-data-erasure/high-volume-erasure/blancco-5/) if you want to be almost positive that the files will not be recovered.

Comment: If I leave the path out will it erase all disks? for example just using "rm -rP" And do you know if any of these are valid options for macos?

"rm -rP -rf" or 

"rm -rP -rf --no-preserve-root"